# Actuarial Problem Help

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

So this is an official Exam P practice problem:

The density of a manufacturer's loss, X,  is given by

$$
f_{X}(x) = \frac{2.5(0.6)^{2.5}}{x^{3.5}}
$$
for x > 0.6 and 0 otherwise.

The manufacturer has an insurance policy with a deductible of 2, after which point all loss is covered. Calculate the expected value of all loss not covered by the insurance company, Y.

I understand how to solve this problem; you split up the integral as such:

$$
E(Y) = \int_{0.6}^{2} xf_X(x)dx + \int_{2}^{\infty}2f_X(x)dx
$$

and you end up getting 0.9343, the correct answer to the problem.

What I'm having trouble doing is connecting this problem back to the theory of conditional expectation that I know.  Y is definitely conditional on X. Y|(0.6<X<2) = x and Y|(X>2) = 2 and 0 otherwise.  How would you define the conditional density of Y given X, and how would you make sense of the conditional expectation formula in the context of this problem?

Comment: In your particular case, you have something like $Y=g(X)\mathbb{1}(X\in A)+h(X)\mathbb{1}(X\in A^c)$. Thus $E[Y]=E[Y;X\in A]+E[Y;X\in A^c]=P[X\in A][Y|X\in A] +P[X\in A^c]E[Y|X\in A^c]$. Here $f_{X|X\in A}=\frac{f_X(x)\mathbb{1}_A(x)}{P[X\in A]}$, similar for $A^c$.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional distribution of $\ Y\ $ given $\ X\ $ is always concentrated at a single atom, namely $\ X\ $ if $\ X<2\ $, or $2$ if $\ X\ge2\ $. It therefore doesn't have a density (unless you allow  [generalized functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) as "densities"), and
$$
E(Y|X)=\cases{X&if $\ X<2$\\
              2&if $\ X\ge2\ $.}
$$
You then have
\begin{align}
E(Y)&=E(E(Y|X))\\
&=\int_{0.6}^\infty E(Y|X=x)f_X(x)dx\\
&=\int_{0.6}^2 xf_X(x)dx+\int_2^\infty2f_X(x)dx\ ,
\end{align}
as you've already found.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you briefly explain what you mean by an "atom?"  I've only studied probability at the undergrad level.

Comment: An atom is a singleton event which has positive probability.   Such an event cannot be expressed as a union of events of smaller porobility.